# QuerySet, use annotate() on multiple fields

Tags: django

This is the **models.py**

```
class CompetitionEntry(models.Model):
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=images, blank=True, null=True)

class CompetitionEntryVote(models.Model):
    voted_entry = models.ForeignKey(CompetitionEntry)

class Entrylikes(models.Model):
    ip_address    = models.IPAddressField()
    liked_entry   = models.ForeignKey(CompetitionEntry)
```

This is the **views.py** (i think problem is here)

```
def show_all_entries(request, id):
    entries = CompetitionEntry.objects.filter(competition__id__exact=comp.id).annotate(vote_count=Count('competitionentryvote'), likes_count=Count('entrylikes'))

    return render(request, "show_all.html", {
        "entries": entries,
        })
```

**show_all.html**

```
{% for item in entries %}

Votes = {{item.vote_count}}   Likes= {{item.likes_count}}

{% endfor %}
```

1. The problem here is that Both the votes and likes are same in the output.
   i,e votes=likes = likes
2. and if i rewrite views  to show only one of either votes or likes , the page works perfectly.
3. and in **views.py** if i used `entries = CompetitionEntry.objects.filter(competition__id__exact=comp.id).annotate(vote_count=Count('competitionentryvote')).annotate(likes_count=Count('entrylikes'))`  I get the same result as 1 above

Comment: I have removed contents from the models.py and views.py above, because they are too large to paste here. Hope this does not takes away the main point out of the question .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Count` aggregate works by mapping to a SQL `COUNT()` expression. See [the documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count).

Since the query you provide will yield only one set of rows for the entire query, the value for `COUNT()` may be the same in your case. You could try to set `distinct=True` as suggested in the documentation:

> If distinct=True, the count will only include unique instances. This is the SQL equivalent of COUNT(DISTINCT ). The default value is False.

I.e.

```
CompetitionEntry.objects.filter(...).annotate(vote_count=Count('competitionentryvote', distinct=True))
   .annotate(likes_count=Count('entrylikes', distinct=True))
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't get the point here(i only have basic knowledge of SQL). So is it not possible include both the counts here ?